# Posix / Thread with join

Tags: pthreads

I read a book, which give the next code:

```
void *printme(void *id) {
    int *i;
    i = (int *)id;
    printf("Hi. I'm thread %d\n", *i);
    return NULL;
}

void main() {
    int i, vals[4];
    pthread_t tids[4];
    void *retval;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        vals[i] = i;
        pthread_create(tids+i, NULL, printme, vals+i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Trying to join with tid%d\n", i);
        pthread_join(tids[i], &retval);
        printf("Joined with tid%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

and the next possible output:

```
Trying to join with tid0 
Hi. I'm thread 0 
Hi. I'm thread 1 
Hi. I'm thread 2 
Hi. I'm thread 3 
Joined with tid0 
Trying to join with tid1 
Joined with tid1 
Trying to join with tid2 
Joined with tid2 
Trying to join with tid3 
Joined with tid3
```

And I don't understand how is it possible. We start with the main thread, and create 4 threads: `tids[0]... tids[3]`. Then, we suspend the execution (by the join instruction): the main thread would wait that `tids[0]` would stop the execution, `tids[0]` would wait to `tids[1]` and so on.

So the output should be:

```
Hi. I'm thread 0 
Hi. I'm thread 1 
Hi. I'm thread 2 
Hi. I'm thread 3 
Trying to join with tid0 
Trying to join with tid1 
Joined with tid0 
Trying to join with tid2 
Joined with tid1 
Trying to join with tid3 
Joined with tid2 
Joined with tid3
```

I feel that I don't understand something really basic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're missing is that `pthread_create` is very different from `fork`.  The created thread starts at the supplied function (`printme`, in this case) and exits as soon as that function returns.  Hence, none of the newly created threads ever reaches the second `for` loop.

Comment: Threads have another execution space, they are just executing the function and they will not expected the reach the second loop, their execution will be printme only. They are not guranteed to work any order, so in that case, all threads are created and control is still in main thread. When join is called, it goes to sleep and any arbitrary thread works. It returns and releases the join on itself.

Answer (score 2):

When you create new thread pthread_create then both thread #1 and main works in parallel. Main goes to next instruction which is phtread_join and hang until thread #1 finishes. This is why you have Trying to join with tid0 , then hello I'm thread #1.

Please also notice that main thread will join child threads in specified order. It means that when you have thread #1, thread #2 and thread #3 and thread 1 takes 10 second to execute, thread 2 takes 6 seconds to execute and thread 3 takes 7 seconds to execute, then first join will take place after 10 seconds and then in few milisecond you should have next joins, since all other thread should finish their jobs.